# Unable to start Spark-standalone in ubuntu

Tags: apache-spark

I'm having trouble while starting spark standalone in my local computer. I'm following [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) manual, which is pretty straightforward but i'm still missing something

When i run start-master.sh, it show the following errors:

```
couto@ubuntu:~/Downloads/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.4/sbin$ sh start-master.sh 
start-master.sh: 31: start-master.sh: [[: not found
start-master.sh: 31: start-master.sh: [[: not found
start-master.sh: 45: start-master.sh: 0: not found
start-master.sh: 52: /home/couto/Downloads/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/load-spark-env.sh: [[: not found
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /home/couto/Downloads/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.4/logs/spark-couto-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-ubuntu.out
start-master.sh: 78: [: false: unexpected operator
```

Nevertheless, the master seems to run right:

[image]

However, once I try to start a slave, it shows the following errors and no slave is included in the spark console.

```
couto@ubuntu:~/Downloads/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.4/sbin$ sh start-slave.sh spark://localhost:7077
start-slave.sh: 42: start-slave.sh: [[: not found
start-slave.sh: 42: start-slave.sh: [[: not found
start-slave.sh: 42: start-slave.sh: [[: not found
start-slave.sh: 52: /home/couto/Downloads/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/load-spark-env.sh: [[: not found
start-slave.sh: 68: start-slave.sh: function: not found
start-slave.sh: 70: shift: can't shift that many
```

I'm using jdk 1.8.0_91
Spark: spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.4 (i also tried with the prebuilt version for hadoop2.6)

Using start-all.sh as suggested in the first comment:

```
couto@ubuntu:~/Downloads/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.4/sbin$ sh start-all.sh 
start-all.sh: 30: start-all.sh: 0: not found
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /home/couto/Downloads/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.4/logs/spark-couto-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-ubuntu.out
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Can you please give me some indications?

Comment: Why you don't use start-all.sh instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Running as follows it worked fine

```
bash start-master.sh 
bash start-slave.sh spark://localhost:7077
```

Kind regards

Comment: Yes, this worked but start-all.sh does not work for me in spark-2.4.4. I have configured SPARK_MASTER_HOST=master on every node and ip of master in /etc/hosts. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Add sbin path in `.bashrc`

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/sbin
```

then run .bashrc

```
source `.bashrc`
```

Answer (score 0):

All the scripts provided by Spark are Bash script and use some Bash-specific syntax. You're trying to run it in using a `sh` interpreter, which causes the error. You should just execute them directly.

```
chmod +x start-all.sh
./start-all.sh
```

Comment: that's not providing the solution

Comment: I beg your pardon ?